# Formula to compare beginning of text in cells only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have formulas in Excel looking for matches by using:

```
 =IF(A2=B2,"Yes","No)
```

I would like to count anything as a yes where the beginning of one matches the other (no matter how many characters).  Some examples of what I would like to return "Yes":

```
  A2               B2
Justin Kelley     Justin K
Just              Justin
Justin K          Justin
```

Some examples of what should return a "No":

```
  A2               B2
Justin Kelley     Kelley Justin
Justin K          Justun K
Justin Kelley     Justin Ki
```

I would normally use the LEFT(1) function here, but it will not capture if there are any differences after the first letter.

Just a little background - there are system errors cutting-off some of my data.  I only want to catch the human errors (the "No" returns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
=IF(IFERROR(LEFT(A2,LEN(B2))=B2,0)+IFERROR(LEFT(B2,LEN(A2))=A2,0),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Tested, doesn't fail; returns proper results.  Clever way to do it +1

Comment: @ExcelHero It works as I described (Thank you so much for that!) but I am having trouble embedding it into my already complex formula:

=IFERROR(IF(B2="NULL","Y",IF(C2="NULL","Y",IF(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""),".","")=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2," ",""),".",""),"Y","N"))),"Y")

Comment: @JustinKelley It's difficult seeing what your goal is here from that formula. Can you send me the workbook showing where and what? I'll sort it out right away. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com